# MongoDB Node-Red (mongodb3) deleteOne script?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, node-red

I am using Node-Red, and I've got a script that pulls a single tweet from a MongoDB collection, but I then want to delete that document. This is what I have so far:

```
let tweets = msg.payload;
let tweet = [];
for (a=1; a < tweets.length; a++)
{
    let n = tweets[a].payload;
    tweet.push(n);
}

let x = Math.floor((Math.random() * tweets.length) + 1);

msg.payload = tweet[x];

return msg;
```

I then have another function to delete the document from MongoDB:

```
let deltweet = msg.payload;
msg.payload = {payload: deltweet}
return msg.payload;
```

Using mongodb3, I have this set to deleteOne, but when I pass the msg.payload I get the following error:

```
"MongoError: BSON field 'delete.deletes.q' is the wrong type 'string', expected type 'object'"
```

The info says "To pass a single parameter to an operation use msg.payload as your parameter (eg {_id: 1243})" but I am unsure how to do that? Any help is appreciated!

Comment: I managed to fix it by doing `return msg;` instead of return `msg.payload;`

I'm a little confused!

Comment: Function nodes (indeed all nodes) must return whole msg objects, not just a value